# Xcode won't compile C-function signature when using reference

Tags: c, xcode, function, reference

Today at the university I wanted do do some C-Coding. I ended up coding under Linux cause Xcode would not let me compile the file.

Since it's probably a simple (hopefully fixable) problem I brought it to the point in some function signatures:

```
void testfunc(int test);
void testfunc(int test, int* test2);
void testfunc(int test, int* test2, int** test3);
```

those 3 will compile and work!
But using

```
void testfunc(int test, int* test2, int** test3, char*& test4);
```

brings Xcode to the opinion that this is not possible. Why? Linux does not complain 'bout that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References don't exist in C. Are you sure you aren't compiling this as C++ under Linux?

Comment: i dont even care if it's c or cpp :) I just wonder how to get XCode to net complain about it. I always use the g++ (gcc) compiler. I already tried setting the file language to "c++" in XCode but it didn't change the fact it's complaining.

Comment: ah sorry, you were right. It just doesnt work by changing the file language but by saying "c++" when creating the file in XCode. Thanks for the help, that did it ;)

Comment: @androidavid: It's complaining because you're trying to compile as C. If you want to compile as CPP the simplest thing is to give the file the proper extension, e.g. .cpp, which will make Xcode automatically pick the right language for compilation.

Comment: @androidavid: When you thought you were changing the file's language I bet you were just changing the syntax coloring. To actually change the language used for compiling on a per-file basis you have to give it the correct compilation flags in the build phase. You can also blanket-override the language used for all files as a build setting (where the default is to build based on the file extension).